# Regex to match everything but the comment

Tags: java, regex

Given this Java regex code for a PSQL statement, I'm having some issues trying to match everything but the comments in the statements. 
This is not getting the lines with the comments in them.

```
^(?!.*?(?:-- [a-z]*-[a-z]*: [a-zA-z]*)).*$
```

This is the PSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE "test_table" (
   "user_id" serial PRIMARY KEY,
   "username" VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL, -- foreign-key: t_supply_type
   "password" VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   "email" VARCHAR (355) UNIQUE NOT NULL, -- foreign-key: t_supply_type
   "created_on" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
   "last_login" TIMESTAMP
);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Generally speaking, you need a parser, not regex, to do this kind of work.  Regex won't cut it.

Comment: Oh hmm, I guess I can look into making a PSQL query parser for this.

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach for your exact data would be to just remove all occurrences of `--` until the end of the line.  Consider:

```
String line = "\"username\" VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL, -- foreign-key: t_supply_type";
line = line.replaceAll("\\s*--.*$", "");
System.out.println(line);
```

This prints:

```
"username" VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
```

Assuming you have already read the entire SQL query into a single string, the above replacement should also still work.